# How to cancel uncompleted install from apt-get update

Tags: apt

I've tried to install docker on my ubuntu but because of server location, I could not install it (403 error). 
Now, when I'm using 'apt-get update' command to install other things, it throws this error:

```
Err:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                        
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.204.214.54 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.204.214.54 443]
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

how I can cancel installing docker?

Comment: try this command in a terminal see if it clear the docker problem sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 163 not upgraded.

Comment: Looks like you have TWO problems, and each requires a separate fix. Fix your *update* problem by editing your sources. Fix your 'cancel installing' problem using the `apt-mark` command.

Comment: How I can edit my source